# Syntax error in string in query expression in shortssize = S

Tags: sql, vb.net, syntax, syntax-error

Im updating an entry in MS Access using this code but it always returns an error. I dont know which part to correct. Please help me i cant seem to find which part is the error

[image]

```
Private Sub SaveChanges()
    con.ConnectionString = OpenDBConnection()
    con.Open()
    Dim sql As String = "Update [JobOrderProd] set [CustomerOrderNumber] = 
    '" & CustomerOrderNumtxtbox.Text & "', [ItemNumber] = '" &
        ItemNumbertxtbox.Text & "', [JerseyName] = '" & 
       JerseyNametxtbox.Text & "', [JerseyNumber] = '"`
        & JerseyNumbertxtbox.Text & "', [JerseySize] = '" & 
          JerseySizetxtbox.Text & "', 
        [ShortsSize] = '" & ShortsSizetxtbox.Text
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)`enter code here`
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`enter code here`
    con.Close()
    MsgBox("Entry for JO Production has been updated.")
    ClearForm()
End Sub
```

Comment: That is a terrible way to write SQL code as it opens you up to all sorts of issues. One is syntax errors because you can't read your own code easily but the more important is SQL injection, which could lead to your whole database being deleted. Learn how to use parameters in your data access code sooner rather than later.

Comment: Also, maybe think about actually looking at your data. If you had actually looked at the VALUE of that `sql` variable instead of just the code that built it then it would have been obvious that you were missing a quote.  As well as using parameters, learn how to debug sooner rather than later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the single inverted comma in the end. add this to the end `& "'"`

```
JerseySizetxtbox.Text & "', 
[ShortsSize] = '" & ShortsSizetxtbox.Text & "'"
```